# QT detect when a given date time is under day light saving or not

Tags: qt, qdatetime, qdate

We have an application that is failing because of DST, we use EST or New york time as our reference, I want to know whethere a given DateTime (QDateTime) is under DST or not, say if I pass Nov 2, 2021 i want to know if that date is under DST (Which it is) or not so we can perform our adjustment.
Is there a way programatically in QT to detect it? or maybe thru standard library time.h?

Comment: What's wrong with [QDateTime::isDaylightTime()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#isDaylightTime) ? Does it not work?

Comment: it always returns false, what i have is I have a unix time, created a QDateTime from it like so; 
QDateTime currTime;
currTime.setTime_t(timestamp);
auto dst = currTime.isDaylightTime();

and it always return false.

Comment: It seems that the time spec is not set (must be Qt::LocalTime or Qt::TimeZone). You can try with `QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch` if your Qt version >= 5.8

Comment: If you don't set a timezone how should isDaylightTime() know it?